# What is the best way to handle close buttons in dialogs in a mobile app?

Tags: popup, dialog, visual-cues, close, mobile-application

I have a small dialog where a user can add an email to subscribe.

I am torn between changing the subscribe button to take 50% of the place and adding cancel or simply make the `x` bigger.

[image: popup example]

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend **going with the cancel option** since most users might not be used to the concept of using the close icon (the X) to close a dialog in a mobile app (you have them in websites) but then with a mobile app the common affordance to what I have found is to to have a distinct cancel option as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the most part I would go with a **dedicated 'Cancel' labelled button** rather than an 'x' on mobile.

The target area is generally to small for the user to have a fluid interaction. If you **make the 'x' a bigger target area** it can be used. A good size might be the one used for delete options(red -). It seems to work quite well for apple so far.

[image]

Not exactly related to your scenario, but a general trend in iOS search/input fields. Put a **small cancel button** near the input field.

[image]